# Does the first level of the Agent of the Grave count as a new level gained for its spell progression?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, character-advancement

The text of the [Agent of the Grave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/agent-of-the-grave/)'s class feature, "Spells Per Day/Spells Known" reads

> When a new Agent of the Grave level is gained, the character gains new spells as if he had also gained a level in a spellcasting class he belonged to before adding the prestige class. He does not, however, gain other benefits a character of that class would have gained, except for additional spells per day, spells known (if he is a spontaneous spellcaster), and an increased effective level of spellcasting. If the character has more than one spellcasting class before becoming an Agent of the Grave he must decide which class he adds the new level to for the purpose of determining spells per day.

When you first gain this prestige class, are you "Gaining a new Agent of the Grave" level, or are you instead selecting this prestige class at level 1, and not getting any benefit of this ability?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the goal to determine if the agent of the grave's text overrules its table?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, at least not in your case

You should look at the "Table: Agent of the Grave" and look at the "Spells" column, which explains the issue. You do not gain spells for your first advancement in Agent of the Grave, but do gain them for any subsequent level in the said Prestige class: it lists "+1 level of existing class" for every level but the first.

Losing a caster level is a serious sacrifice, but that's it. You could house rule it with your GM if it gets inconvenient for you -- be careful, though, you might break the balance.

To answer such a question yourself, look at the "Spells" column in any class's table, if nothing is listed there, you gain no spells when advancing in said class.